# Should I flag questions for migration?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration, moderation

Let's say there is a question that is strictly Linux-related and it asks about specific Linux commands, which has nothing to do with programming. For example: [grep select line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292928/grep-select-line)

[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) isn't one of the five **Off Topic** migration options (I think it would be  a good replacement for TeX, personally).

Should I flag (not close) the question and ask a moderator to migrate it to the appropriate SE site?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, when you feel a question is more suitable to another site, one that you can't vote to migrate on, flagging for moderation attention would be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should obviously ask moderator to migrate it to the appropriate SE site because SO is one who is there for providing the information to the people who need the help.

So people obviously search them in an appropriate place.