# When should I flag off-topic questions for migration?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, flags, migration

Let's say I come across a recently posted question on Stack Overflow which is clearly better suited for another Stack Exchange site.

Let's also assume that the site it belongs on is not one of the automatic migration targets listed in the "close as off topic" menu (which it usually isn't — the SE network is big, and automatic migration targets are few and far between).

**How should I deal with it?**

- *a)* Flag it for ♦ moderator attention, with a note saying "*Migrate to whatever.SE.*"
- *b)* Vote to close it as off topic, and leave a polite comment pointing the asker to the other site.
- *c)* Both of the above.
- *d)* Something else.

Also, should the decision depend on whether the question already has answers?  Or on whether it already has an *accepted* (or highly upvoted and clearly correct) answer?

---

**Ps.** For some background, my usual approach in the past has been *(a)* — flag the question promptly for migration, so that it can be cleanly and smoothly rerouted to the appropriate site, while ensuring that anyone else finding the question on Google will also be sent to the right place.

I'm aware that, by doing so, I've been creating extra work for the ♦ mods, but nobody's explicitly complained about it so far, and [past meta threads on the subject](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146081/should-i-flag-questions-for-migration) have pretty clearly implied that this is appropriate.

However, lately I've seen a few of these flags declined, and also *many* of them accepted as "helpful" but without the question actually being migrated.  So, naturally, I'm starting to wonder if I'm handling these situations the wrong way, and whether there's some better approach (like, say, *(b)* above)?

I'd particularly like to get some "official" feedback from the SO mods: give that you end up making the final call anyway, what sort of questions should I and should I not send your way?

**Pps.** For more concrete context, here are some recent example entries (in reverse chronological order) from my flag history since Christmas:

- <sub><sup>[Best way to send email when PHP process dies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058458/best-way-to-send-email-when-php-process-dies): flagged as "*Migrate to serverfault.*"; awaiting review.</sup></sub>
- <sub><sup>[How to find private key in RSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076966/how-to-find-private-key-in-rsa): flagged as "*Migrate to crypto.SE.*"; flag deemed helpful, post closed as off topic by a ♦ mod, but not migrated.</sup></sub>
- <sub><sup>[DES key expansion: why are these two descriptions different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074175/des-key-expansion-why-are-these-two-descriptions-different): flagged as "*Migrate to crypto.SE.*"; awaiting review.</sup></sub>
- <sub><sup>[Rule Handling for a Mao (Card Game)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064935/rule-handling-for-a-mao-card-game): flagged as "*More of a design than a programming question. Migrate to gamedev.SE?*", also left a comment pointing the OP to gamedev.SE; flag deemed helpful, post deleted by OP but not, apparently, reposted anywhere.</sup></sub>
- <sub><sup>[Why should a salt have the same length as the hashed value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064227/why-should-a-salt-have-the-same-length-as-the-hashed-value): flagged as "*Migrate to crypto.SE.*", also left comment and voted to close; flag deemed helpful, post closed as off topic by 5 voters including me, not migrated.</sup></sub>
- <sub><sup>[how to find an open webform on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058317/how-to-find-an-open-webform-on-my-website): flagged as "*Off topic, migrate to webmasters.SE or security.SE.*"; flag deemed helpful, post closed by a ♦ mod, not migrated.</sup></sub>
- <sub><sup>[Booting BZ image on qEmu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047598/booting-bz-image-on-qemu): flagged as "*Migrate to unix.SE?*", also voted to close; flag deemed helpful, post closed by 5 voters, not migrated.</sup></sub>
- <sub><sup>[GMAIL API for visualizing inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035593/gmail-api-for-visualizing-inbox): flagged as "*Migrate to webapps.SE?*", also voted to close: flag deemed helpful, post closed by 5 voters, not migrated.</sup></sub>
- <sub><sup>[Xming gedit not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042450/xming-gedit-not-displayed): flagged as "*Migrate to ServerFault?*", also voted to close; flag declined, post closed by 5 voters.</sup></sub>
- <sub><sup>[Does Apple notify me if my bug which has been marked as a duplicate has been addressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043207/does-apple-notify-me-if-my-bug-which-has-been-marked-as-a-duplicate-has-been-add): flagged as "*Migrate to Ask Different?*", also voted to close; flag deemed helpful, post closed by 5 voters, not migrated.</sup></sub>
- <sub><sup>[Website sometimes slow down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043343/website-sometimes-slow-down): flagged as "*Off topic, migrate to webmasters.SE?*"; flag deemed helpful, post closed by 5 voters, not migrated.</sup></sub>
- <sub><sup>[Bash prompt script with an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043129/bash-prompt-script-with-an-error): flagged as "*Migrate to unix.SE?*", also voted to close; flag deemed helpful, post closed by 5 voters, not migrated.</sup></sub>
- <sub><sup>[Image encryption, resistant to scaling and color grading - is there an algorythm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041545/image-encryption-resistant-to-scaling-and-color-grading-is-there-an-algorythm): flagged as "*Off topic for SO. Should be on topic for crypto.SE, migrate there?*"; flag declined, post closed by 5 voters.</sup></sub>
- <sub><sup>[Http basic Authentication instead of TlS client certificaiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043397/http-basic-authentication-instead-of-tls-client-certificaiton): flagged as "*Migrate to security.SE?*"; flag deemed helpful, post still open and not migrated.</sup></sub>
- <sub><sup>[Secure data in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032366/secure-data-in-database): flagged as "*Not really a programming question. Migrate to security.SE?"*; flag declined with custom note "*This is not a high-quality question, so should not be migrated.*", post closed as not constructive by 5 voters.</sup></sub>
- <sub><sup>[Bash terminal and color output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031779/bash-terminal-and-color-output): flagged as "*Migrate to unix.SE?*"; flag deemed helpful, post closed by a ♦ mod, not migrated.</sup></sub>
- <sub><sup>[Initial states with interpolated fixed time steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031812/initial-states-with-interpolated-fixed-time-steps): flagged as "*Migrate to gamedev.SE?*"; flag deemed helpful, post still open and not migrated.</sup></sub>

That's 17 flags over about four (admittedly busy) days, three of them declined and not a single one actioned.  That kind of suggests to me that I must be doing *something* wrong here.

I'm happy to also receive any critique, even harsh, on those specific flags (especially if accompanied by helpful advice on how to deal with such cases better), but what I'm mainly hoping for is more general feedback that could be useful to others as well; I only added the list to make it clear what kind of questions and flags I'm taking about.

Comment: Note that the destination site moderators have something to say about migrations as well. The 'local' mod may agree it's a migration candidate, but the quality of the post is such that the *target* site moderator declines it. Your flag is then still helpful, but the post won't be migrated. What makes a good migration candidate thus can vary by target site as much as anything.

Comment: It is possible you are seeing more declined flags because the [moderators are taking a more strict approach with flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160754/182513) recently, where previously if they felt you were wrong but trying to be helpful, it was marked as helpful.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Actually, I'm fine with that.  If I make a bad flagging decision, I'd rather see it declined (ideally with a helpful note for the future) than accepted and silently forgotten.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I am as well for the same reasons.... I linked the post here just because I thought it might be relevant.

Comment: The first thing to do is think quality, neither of the examples you suggested should go to SF would pass my quality test for migration. Once you decide something is good enough to migrate, then consider 'fit' for the target site.

Comment: @Iain: Fair enough. I guess I was thinking that, even if they're weak, it would be better to have them be weak and on topic than weak and _off_ topic. Admittedly, I'm not too familiar with SF quality standards (which probably means I shouldn't be flagging any more questions for migration there), but neither of them seemed _so_ bad to me that I would've voted to close them for poor quality alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When all of the following criteria apply:

1. The question could not be closed for any of the other reasons.
2. The question isn't more than 60 days old (regular users and moderators can no longer vote for migration, but nothing stops users from flagging it anyways).
3. You are familiar enough with the target site to know, with 100% certainty, that it belongs there.

If the question does not meet any one of those, just vote to close it and move on.

Comment: Thanks.  Just to clarify, if the question is low-quality but salvageable, does that mean I should edit it before flagging, rather than waiting to see whether it will be migrated or not?

Comment: Yes, always edit to improve it if you can. They don't know you want to improve it, only that it looks bad as it is.

Comment: That last one, being familiar enough with the target site, is the hardest. Server Fault was removed as a migration target because people _thought_ they knew what was on topic there and were mistaken approximately half the time.

Comment: @Michael: It would be nice if rep on the target site could factor into the process somehow. I may not be an infallible authority on what's on topic for, say, crypto.SE, but [I think I might have some vague idea about it](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/129/alltime/crypto/2011-07-12/598?sort=reputationchange#598).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen At the moment, moderators do not migrate questions to beta sites, so a comment which leads people to your beta site would probably be best.

Comment: @Michael: What, really? [That's definitely news to me.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136687/is-it-possible-to-migrate-questions-to-a-beta-se-site) I'm sure I've seen migrated posts on beta sites before. (In fact, I just [linked to one](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1713/calculating-private-keys-in-the-rsa-cryptosystem) in another comment.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I said that they _do_ not, not that they _can_ not. My understanding is there's some sort of policy reason for not doing it now, though I don't have the specifics handy.

Comment: @Michael: According to http://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats, in the last 90 days there were 71 questions migrated from SO to codereview.SE, 21 to dsp.SE, 15 to cs.SE, 10 to crypto.SE and 8 to other beta sites. [The latest one was yesterday.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099177?noredirect=1) I'd say that pretty conclusively suggests that the mods _do_, in fact, migrate questions to beta sites.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: I've never personally heard of not migrating to beta sites, but I remember there was a lot of controversy with very old and highly upvoted questions being migrated to beta sites, since it put them clear ahead of other questions and skewed the beta statistics.

Answer (score 10):

The majority of those questions are just way too low-quality to migrate anywhere.  One or two of the following might be *salvagable*, but that's really the best I can say.  None of them are *really great* questions that we should be in a hurry to migrate anywhere.  I think all of these would be closed on the target site if they were migrated.

- [Secure data in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032366/secure-data-in-database)
- [Image encryption, resistant to scaling and color grading - is there an algorythm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041545/image-encryption-resistant-to-scaling-and-color-grading-is-there-an-algorythm)
- [Bash prompt script with an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043129/bash-prompt-script-with-an-error)
- [Website sometimes slow down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043343/website-sometimes-slow-down)
- [Does Apple notify me if my bug which has been marked as a duplicate has been addressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043207/does-apple-notify-me-if-my-bug-which-has-been-marked-as-a-duplicate-has-been-add)
- [Xming gedit not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042450/xming-gedit-not-displayed)
- [GMAIL API for visualizing inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035593/gmail-api-for-visualizing-inbox)
- [how to find an open webform on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058317/how-to-find-an-open-webform-on-my-website)
- [Booting BZ image on qEmu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047598/booting-bz-image-on-qemu)
- [How to find private key in RSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076966/how-to-find-private-key-in-rsa)

You can improve your accept rate on these types of flags if you only flag questions that are of really high quality, and that you *know* the community on another site will want.  If you're not 100% sure it would be a great question on another site, just vote to close it where it's at.

Comment: Thanks. I still think the image encryption question _could_ be made into an interesting question for crypto.SE, but I agree that the way it's written is not too great. (Crypto is a fairly quiet site, so we tend to spend more effort on salvaging weak questions than SO does, or possibly could.) And I don't think we'd close the RSA question just for poor quality, either, although [we might close it as a duplicate](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1713/calculating-private-keys-in-the-rsa-cryptosystem).

Comment: I guess what most bothers me about questions like the RSA one is that they've already slipped in through the gap -- they already have a correct, well written answer on SO, so just closing them after the fact amounts to little more than slapping an "off topic" sticker on them.  It does nothing to lead the user to the correct site for such questions, or to discourage other users from asking more such questions on SO.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Downvoting and closing as off-topic does discourage other users from asking the same kinds of questions on SO.  A comment might lead the user to the correct site, but I'd rather not encourage such low-quality questions on any SE site.