# Policy for flagging a question as off-topic when it already has an answer

Tags: discussion, flags, off-topic, low-quality-posts

I saw a question which, to me, was off-topic.  (Taking the answer below into account I would have flagged it if it were not for my question).  I thought to flag it but noticed **there was an answer in place**.  What should be considered (in terms of 'maybe it should not be flagged since it has an answer' when flagging when there's an answer in place?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160816/when-should-i-flag-off-topic-questions-for-migration

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the migration question.  My question is different.

Comment: Flag the question, lots of questions that are not on topic, have answers

Comment: Flag for a migration or just to close? It depends

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some people have different (possibly even wrong) opinions than you do as to a question's off-topic-ness. Believing it to be on-topic, they may answer it. When you see an answer, you see that at least one person believes it's on-topic, or not unclear, or whatever.

If you disagree, and are sure yourself that's it's off-topic, then go ahead and do what you do when you see an off-topic question (vote to close or flag, according to your rep level.) The existence of the answer means nothing more than that one person on the entire internet doesn't share your opinion. Go ahead and consider that, but don't let it be a prohibition against acting according to your position on the question.